# Order of using free registers in the stack

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Assuming my program calls to a function:

```
void f(int arr[], int size)
{
  int i, j, k;
  // other code
}
```

In what order the compiler (gcc) is using the *caller save* registers: %eax, %ecx, %edx ?

Will it also use one of the *calle save* registers: %ebx, %esi, %edi in this case?

Comment: It actually doesn't have to. In fact, general purpose registers don't have to be preserved, and if they're used instead of the stack frame, it's only because of the optimization.

Comment: The only way to find out is to try it and see. (Use the `-s` option to output assembly code)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried the -S flag but I don't really understand the whole output. About the optimization, if i'm using -o I understand that the compiler can use 4 registers, so in what order is it using them, first the parameters or the local vars?

Comment: Did you try typing in "gcc calling conventions" into an internet search engine? [This result](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/asm/calling.html) appears to answer all of your questions.

Comment: The compiler isn't required to use registers in any particular order (or at all). GCC doesn't use registers in a predictable order and the mapping of variables to registers is often not 1:1. A variable might live in different registers over its lifetime, while the same register might be used for a number of different variables.